# update textview in an Activity from a background service even when application is closed

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I want to update the UI every 5 seconds after calling a web service even if the app is closed. I have created a service and using broadcast receiver i am getting the data from server but when the application is closed the last response from server should be updated, but when i open the app last response data is not updated.

Below is the code snippet

**MainActivity.java**

```
import java.text.DateFormat;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView name1, name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
    name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name1);


    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourService.class));

}

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get extra data included in the Intent
        String nameStr = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String name1Str = intent.getStringExtra("name1");
        name.setText(nameStr);
        name1.setText(name1Str);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
   super.onResume();
   //registerReceiver(statusReceiver,mIntent);
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).registerReceiver(
           mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("UIValues"));
 }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {

   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
   super.onPause();
  }
 }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:hint="md5"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:hint="name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**YourService.java**

```
import learn2crack.asynctask.library.JSONParser;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class YourService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "Your Service";

private final Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

    }
};
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);   
}
 private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             new JSONParse().execute();

            /// Any thing you want to do put the code here like web service procees it will run in ever 1 second
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000); // 5 seconds
        }
 };
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

    handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
    handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000);//1 second       
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
}

 private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);  // server url
        return json;
    }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
         try {
            if(json != null){

             JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(json.toString());
             String name = reader.getString("name");
             String name1 = reader.getString("name1");
              Intent intent = new Intent("UIValues");
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("name1", name1);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

**JSONParser.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.asynctask"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.asynctask.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.asynctask.YourService"></service>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone help me solving this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Doing anything every 5 seconds is horrible for battery life. Users have complained **very loudly** about this, and so Google continues to take steps to prevent apps from doing this. For example, Doze mode and app standby on Android 6.0+ will cause your jobs to run very infrequently, on the order of once an hour or less. And on Android 8.0+, your service will be stopped after ~1 minute.

Comment: Why dont you use Firebase for this, it will solve your problem easily. If i get data from Firebase and set it in textview, update it in Firebase,, it will update then and there.

Comment: @CommsWare service should be called every 30 seconds that is the requirement

Comment: @Rishabh Dugar i don't want to use firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably save the last response in persistant storage (file, sharedprefernce) and simply read it once the app is opened and show the last response.

Answer (score 0):

Store your response to the `SharedPreferences` as well, when the activity is not opened its views will not get updated from the service in your case the activity will not be receiving broadcast when its closed. On the other hand if you have latest response stored in shared preferences, you can read the value on the activity created and set that value in the view.
This will ensure that you get the latest response on the view.

Answer (score 0):

When your app is not closed, you cannot know if the data is updated or not. And there is no point in updating the UI of app when it is not visible to user. What you need is that it should be updated every time the application is opened.
In your service you can store the data and fetch it in your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method of your activity.

Enjoy Coding.!!